# SSIS File System store - Is there a file path I can use for access

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS File System deployment and I am trying to understand if there is any easy way to deploy a large number of packages. The name implies that it is a physical directory on the disk, that I could copy/paste the files to, but I cannot find anything online that tells me where this directory lives.

Am I correct in thinking it works this way? Or will I need to either manually upload each package in SSMS or script an automated deployment

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your current files reside in:

```
\[your]\[computer]\pdevine\Documents\Visual Studio [yourVersion]\Projects
```

After creating a solution on the target, you can just copy and paste the files into the project directory for the target.  If you don't know where to find your current files, click on any package and look here:

[image]

Comment: This is where the development files live, I'm talking about a file system storage when deploying to the server (as an alternative to using MSDB)

Comment: Right, so create a solution on the server and copy your files into the solution.  You can also deploy remotely using dtutil but it's a real pain.  I'll put that in the answer too in case you want to try it...

EDIT: dtutil does not work for file system -> file system, my mistake

Comment: ah, so I can only manually upload packages into the file system mode?

Comment: That is correct. If you're on sql server 2012 or higher, I'd recommend transitioning to SSISDB and doing Project Deployment as it's a breeze to deploy to multiple environments.  If you're stuck on File System, then version control or manual upload is your best bet.